# cannot expose port using kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile

My objective: To expose a pod's(running angular image) `port` so that I can **access it from the host machine's browser**.

service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:  
  name: my-frontend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 4200
```

Pod's yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: angular.frontend
  labels:
    app: MyApp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: angular-frontend-demo
    image: angular-frontend-image
    ports:
    - name: nodejs-port
      containerPort: 4200
```

Weird thing is that doing `kubectl port-forward pod/angular.frontend 8000:4200` works. However, my objective is to write that in `service.yml`

Answer (score 2):

Use Nodeport:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:  
  name: my-frontend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 4200
    nodePort: 30001
```

then you can access the service on nodeport 30001 on any node of the cluster.

For example the machine name is node01 , you can then do curl http://node01:30001

Comment: (If it’s Minikube, “any node of the cluster” is only the Minikube IP address, usually 192.168.99.100.  You can only pick a port between 32000 and 32767.)

Comment: My objective is to "access it from the host machine's browser. "

Comment: yes , you should be able to access it from machine browser if there is a route from your machine to the node01

Answer (score 1):

The service you've defined here is of type `ClusterIP` (since you haven't set a `type` in the `spec`). This means the service is only available and [reachable within the cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types). You can use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to make it accessible from outside the cluster, see for example [this post](https://medium.com/@Oskarr3/setting-up-ingress-on-minikube-6ae825e98f82) showing how to do that for Minikube.

Comment: I cannot do that without using ingress?

Comment: Sure, there are other options such as `NodePort` as mentioned above but if you only want to access it locally, there's nothing wrong with a good old port-forward ;)